# Two inner joins and a where on first clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10' 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id WHERE wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00')
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK')
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```

Any reason why it doesn't work, but if I remove the second `INNER JOIN` it works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `WHERE` in the inner join condition.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10' 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00')
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK')
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two 'WHERE' statements. That could be a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes: While there might be some `wp_postmeta` that have corresponding `wp_term_relationships`, and some that have `wp_posts`, there are none that have both.

To find out more about your data, change your joins to `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `WHERE` clauses in the same query.

All you need to do is either move the first `WHERE` condition into the existing clause, or just make it an `AND` for the Join:

Either:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10'  
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00') 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK') 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta       
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10'  
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('AU', 'US', 'JP', 'BR', 'UK') 
AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 18:00:00') 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.post_id DESC
```